# R Fill cells with previous data

Tags: r, date, loops, replace

I have a table like the following:

```
    days    Debit   loaddate    
1   23/01/2014  138470289.4 23/01/2014  
2   24/01/2014  NA  NA  
3   25/01/2014  NA  NA  
4   26/01/2014  NA  NA  
5   27/01/2014  NA  NA
```

one row for each day and then in the columns loaddate after a few NA another date appears:

```
28  19/02/2014  NA  NA  
29  20/02/2014  NA  NA  
30  21/02/2014  NA  NA  
31  22/02/2014  9090967.9   22/02/2014  
32  23/02/2014  NA  NA  
33  24/02/2014  308083.5    24/02/2014
```

I would like to replace each NA in loaddate column with the previous date in loaddate.

I tried:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data3)) 
    { if (!is.na(data3[i,'Debit'])) 
          {data3[i,'loaddate1']<-as.Date(data3[i,'loaddate'], format='%Y-%m-%d')}
      else {data3[i,'loaddate1']<-data3[i-1,'loaddate1']}
}
```

But I got the wrong format:

```
> head(data3)
        days     Debit   loaddate loaddate1
1 2014-01-23 138470289 2014-01-23     16093
2 2014-01-24        NA       <NA>     16093
3 2014-01-25        NA       <NA>     16093
4 2014-01-26        NA       <NA>     16093
5 2014-01-27        NA       <NA>     16093
6 2014-01-28        NA       <NA>     16093
```

I need to get the date format also. If I do:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data3)) 
    { if (!is.na(data3[i,'Debit'])) 
          {data3[i,'loaddate1']<-as.Date(data3[i,'loaddate'], format='%Y-%m-%d')}
      else {data3[i,'loaddate1']<-as.Date(data3[i-1,'loaddate1'], format='%Y-%m-%d')}
}
```

I got the wrong result (with NA).

```
        days     Debit   loaddate loaddate1
1 2014-01-23 138470289 2014-01-23     16093
2 2014-01-24        NA       <NA>      <NA>
3 2014-01-25        NA       <NA>      <NA>
4 2014-01-26        NA       <NA>      <NA>
5 2014-01-27        NA       <NA>      <NA>
6 2014-01-28        NA       <NA>      <NA>
```

How can I get the right result and with the right format?
Also, Is there a better way to do this replacement? I mean without a loop.
Thanks.

Comment: So row 32 should be `22/02/2014`?

Comment: yes, row 32 should be 22/02/2014

Comment: Try `na.locf(df$loaddate)` from `library(zoo)`

Comment: Is there always a date in the very first row?

Comment: yes. in the 1st row is always a date

Answer (score 4):

Try `zoo::na.locf` and make sure to use the appropriate date format:

```
library(zoo)
data3$loaddate <- as.Date(na.locf(data3$loaddate), format='%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Comment: I get the same. It's not filling the NA

Comment: str(data3$loaddate)
 Date[1:348], format: "2014-01-23" NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
Warning message:
In as.POSIXlt.Date(x) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: If that's how your data looks **before** you run what I suggested, then you should just run `data3$loaddate <- na.locf(data3$loaddate)`. I'm a bit confused why your example shows dates like `22/02/2014` though.

Comment: Have you figured it out, if not, can you clarify the discrepancies?